# createhomedir not working on 10.14.2

Tags: terminal

Having search the wide space of the WWW I could not find any hint why, after setting up a new user using *dscl*, using *createhomedir* does not create the newly created user's home directory.

I do:

```
sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -create /Users/bobby
sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -create /Users/bobby passwd ""
sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -create /Users/bobby UniqueID 30001
sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -create /Users/bobby PrimaryGroupID 20001
sudo /usr/bin/dscl . -create /Users/bobby NFSHomeDirectory /Users/bobby
sudo /usr/sbin/createhomedir -c -u bobby
sudo /usr/bin/pwpolicy -setpolicy "newPasswordRequired=1"
```

(This is run from within a bash script)

No directory is created under /Users ... Checking that creating the user's ds entry actually worked with *dscl . read /Users/bobby* shows that this indeed **did** work.

EDIT:

I also tried this now using *sysadminctl* like so:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sysadminctl -addUser bobby -UID 30001 -password "" -home /Users/bobby -admin
```

still no luck.

Thanks for any hints.

Regards 
   Frank

Comment: Oh my - I did find _sysadminctl_ now - so this part of my question is answered. Sorry for the noise. // Frank

Comment: check out my [useradd.sh](https://gist.github.com/igorvoltaic/ff3eed83aa0c37a85d1802b4fa40609a)

Comment: Also you do not need so many `sudo`s. `sudo ./scriptName` is perfectly fine.