# Create User via Terminal with Bash in macOS Mojave

Tags: terminal, security, bash, mojave

In general, you can create a user via Terminal in macOS using Apple's [documented method](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203998). However, macOS Mojave introduced various security mechanisms that cause scripts to fail when changing user account settings like UID and NFSHomeDirectory, both of which I need to change for how I use these accounts. So, the script to create a new home folder now fails, unless I have a GUI to approve the change being made. Is there any way to create a user and modify the settings without disabling any security settings? There's nothing in the [TCC database](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/10/10/watching-mojaves-privacy-protection-at-work/) I can find to allow this script to run, and it's not feasible to run this on every machine I need it deployed to.

I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
new_uid=401
username=xmpleuser
homefolder=/var/xmplfolder
sudo dscl . -delete Users/$username
sudo rm -r $homefolder
echo "Creating $username ( $new_uid ) user..."
sudo dscl . -create /Users/$username UniqueID $new_uid
sudo dscl . -append /Users/$username NFSHomeDirectory $homefolder
sudo dscl . -append /Users/$username home $homefolder
sudo dscl . -append /Users/$username UserShell /sbin/nologin
```

And I've tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
new_uid=401
username=xmpleuser
homefolder=/var/xmplfolder
sudo dscl . -delete Users/$username
sudo rm -r $homefolder
sudo sysadminctl -addUser $username -UID $new_uid -shell /sbin/nologin -home $homefolder
```

They both give a warning box:
[image: "App" would like to administer your computer]

I also tried the script linked on [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/350022/createhomedir-not-working-on-10-14-2) question, and the exact Terminal commands in the Apple article mentioned earlier.

Comment: It works if you use ssh to login into an admin account, either locally or remote.

Comment: Could you verify the version of macOS you are running on the machine you're remotely connected to? `sw_vers` in Terminal should give it to you.

Comment: 10.14.5 (and 10.14.4 before). But I just tried again, the results are, hmm, strange. Using just `dscl` sometimes works and sometimes fails (haven't found a pattern yet), using `sysadminctl` always fails. Going to delete my answer in a day, isn't really helpful if it doesn't work reliably.